# Cast of const_iterator to iterator& in definition of std::set

Tags: c++, casting, stl, iterator, set

C++ STL uses a red-black tree to store data inside `std::set` and `std::map`. I noticed that `set::iterator` is actually a typedef of the const iterator of the red black tree:

```
//All code snippets taken from SGI STL. https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/

typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Identity<value_type>, key_compare, _Alloc> _Rep_type;
typedef typename _Rep_type::const_iterator iterator;
```

This is reasonable because users are supposed not to modify the content of the set through an iterator. But `set` has to implement operations like `insert` and `erase`, which calls for a non-const iterator of the red-black tree. SGI STL uses a c-style cast to do this:

```
void erase(iterator __position) { 
  typedef typename _Rep_type::iterator _Rep_iterator;
  _M_t.erase((_Rep_iterator&)__position); 
}
```

I'm wondering:

1. Why is this cast safe? It is casting `_Rep_type::const_iterator` to `_Rep_type::iterator&`.
2. How to write the cast in C++ style? [I've tried to do it](http://ideone.com/0nCuvM): Neither `static_cast` nor `const_cast` will do the job. `reinterpret_cast` can compile, but I'm not sure if it does the same thing as the C-style cast.

Comment: Re: "typedef of the const iterator" -- be very careful here: it's actually "typedef of the const_iterator". A "const_iterator" is not a "const iterator" and vice versa. A "const_iterator" cannot be used to modify the data that it points at. A "const iterator" cannot itself be modified, but it may or may not be able to modify the data it points at, depending on whether it is, in fact, a const_iterator.

Answer (score 0):

`iterator` and `_Rep_type::iterator` are instances of the same class template, the former using `const` qualified types and the latter using the same, but non-`const` types. Something like this:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct B {};

using S = B<int&, int*>;
using Sconst = B<const int&, const int*>;
```

So for your questions:

1. It is safe because the two types have the exact same memory layout.
2. You cannot use `static_cast` because the compiler considers the types to be unrelated. You have to bring in the heavy artillery, `reinterpret_cast`:

```cpp
int test() {
    S s;
    Sconst& sconst = reinterpret_cast<Sconst&>(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A C-Cast has no direct mapping to one specific C++ cast.

But a C-Cast can be mapped to one or more C++ casts.

When doing a C-Cast you can think of the compiler trying this set of C++ casts in order. The first one that is valid is what the C++ compiler will do: (see also [C++ Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/14065), In [N4917](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/n4917.pdf) 7.6.3 Explicit type conversion (cast notation) [expr.cast])

1. const_cast
2. static_cast
3. static_cast followed by const_cast
4. reinterpret_cast
5. reinterpret_castfollowed by const_cast

So looking at your example, it looks like option 3 or 5 (but would need to try it with a compiler to be sure).

```
 (_Rep_iterator&)__position

 // Maps to:

 const_cast<_Rep_iterator&>(static_cast<_Rep_iterator const&>(__position))

 // or

 const_cast<_Rep_iterator&>(reinterpret_cast<_Rep_iterator const&>(__position))
```